# how to remove common elements in a column in 5 data frame in R

Tags: r, unique

I have 5 data frames:

```
a <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), peak = c("peak1", "peak2", "peak3", "peak4", "peak10"))
b <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), peak = c("peak1","peak3", "peak20", "peak21"))
c <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "2", "3"), peak = c("peak1", "peak5", "peak3"))
d <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),peak = c("peak1", "peak3", "peak7", "peak8", "peak11", "peak12"))
e <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "2", "3"), peak = c("peak1", "peak3",  "peak9"))
```

I would like to remove the common peaks across the data frames, with a desired outputs:

```
a <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), peak = c("peak2", "peak4", "peak10"))
b <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), peak = c("peak20", "peak21"))
c <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "2", "3"), peak = c("peak5", ))
d <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),peak = c(  "peak7", "peak8", "peak11", "peak12"))
e <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "2", "3"), peak = c(  "peak9"))
```

I know how to compare two data frames `a[!(a$peak %in% b$peak),]` but I'm struggling with 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following approach :

```
#Put the data in a list
list_df <- dplyr::lst(a, b, c, d, e)
#Get the common peak value
common_peak <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(list_df, `[[`, 'peak'))
common_peak
#[1] "peak1" "peak3"

#Remove the common peak value from all the dataframes
result <- lapply(list_df, function(x) subset(x, !peak %in% common_peak))
result

#$a
#  ID   peak
#2  2  peak2
#4  4  peak4
#5  5 peak10

#$b
#  ID   peak
#3  3 peak20
#4  4 peak21

#$c
#  ID  peak
#2  2 peak5

#$d
#  ID   peak
#3  3  peak7
#4  4  peak8
#5  5 peak11
#6  6 peak12

#$e
#  ID  peak
#3  3 peak9

#Update all the individual dataframes
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: and it could be any easy approach to do it if any peak comes out in >=  3 data frames?

Comment: No, that would require more complicated calculations since we would need to store each peaks count. Maybe you can ask that as a new question.